# Why doesn't text start at 0,0?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout, graphics, uilabel

This problem with iOS is something that's been bugging me for a while:

I'll lay out my elements as I want them to look, when designing. Going into coding, I measure the distances between things in order to correctly place each element. Using `UIImageView` or `drawRect:` on an image works fine, and puts it into the right place, at the right size. Using `UILabel` or `drawRect`: on text however, does not start it at the correct point - its a few pixels out. I end up going back into Photoshop and measuring the distance that it is, compared to the distance it should be, in order to figure out how much I need to adjust it's position. I have to do this every time I draw text. Is there a solution to this problem that I don't know about.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean? And possibly include some code.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this is that drawing text at a `CGPoint` of `(0, 0)` is specifying the baseline of the text, and not the top-left corner. You need to get the baseline of your text, and offset it by that amount, or use `drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:` as specified here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps.